# Rotation of intersected objects to face the camera in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have objects created on click which have the position defined, but the rotation is not updated when the camera is moved around. I tried to use the `lookAt` package to face the camera, but it does not update the rotation. 
It's my first attempt at a-frame, and here in the https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/d5172092-db53-4ddf-aa60-c8cdf3bc4000 to my code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If possible, please include your code in your question so that when (not if) the link goes bad, your question will retain its context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spawning entities defined in a `mixin`. You could add the `look-at` component to the mixin :

```
<a-mixin id="note" <stuff> look-at='#camera'>
```

which will apply the rotation upon creation. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnqfmv4/1/).